# Exception Thrown by the target of an invocation when accessing a 3rd party dll

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, console-application, nullreferenceexception, dll-reference

I have been working on a C# console application which uses a number of 3rd party dlls which are referenced in the project.

Everything was working fine but one day my windows 7 operating system updated because of automatic windows update and after that this application code started crashing at the code where a call is made to a 3rd party dll which actually accessing the database.

I restored my system to a previous state and the application started working fine again but once again the windows update ran and application started crashing again at the same location.

I can not stop windows update as its a company provided laptop and I can not change setting so that windows update do not happen again. And I do not have the code for this 3rd party dll.

I can provide you the app.config here...

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <configuration>
              <configSections>
                <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
                <section name="databaseSection" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSection,Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data"/>
                <section name="cafe.frameworks.foundationAbstraction" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.Configuration.FoundationAbstractionSectionHandler, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.AdapterFactory"/>
                <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.Configuration.LoggingConfigurationSection, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                <section name="exceptionManagement" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement.Configuration.ExceptionManagementSection, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>

              </configSections>

              <!--<databaseSection performanceCountersEnabled="false" />
              <exceptionManagement performanceCountersEnabled="false" />-->

              <databaseSection defaultDatabase="Sql" dbCommandTimeOut="3000">
                <databases>
                  <add name="Sql" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data.SqlHelper,Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data" connectionStringName="Sql"/>
                </databases>
              </databaseSection>


              <log4net>
                <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
                  <file value="C:\ApplicationLogs\BGTs\AA\v1.0\AABackgroundTask\Files\Log\AABLog.txt"/>
                  <appendToFile value="true"/>
                  <maximumFileSize value="1500KB"/>
                  <maxSizeRollBackups value="20"/>
                  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
                  </layout>
                </appender>
                <root>
                  <level value="DEBUG"/>
                  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
                </root>
              </log4net>


              <connectionStrings>
                     -----deleted
              </connectionStrings>

              <appSettings>
                <!--Production-->
                <!-- PROCESS DELAY SECTION -->
                <add key="ProcessDelay" value="0"/>

                <!-- INBOUND -->
                <add key="IB_GlobalVarCreation" value="GlobalVarCreation"/>
                <add key="IB_RoutingScript_In" value="RoutingScript_In"/>

                <!-- OUTBOUND -->
                <add key="OB_CampaignCreation" value="CampaignCreation"/>
                <add key="OB_RoutingScript_Out" value="RoutingScript_Out"/>
                <add key="OB_AdminScript_Agent" value="AdminScript_Agent"/>
                <add key="OB_DisableCampaign" value=" DisableCampaign"/>

                <!-- INBOUND & OUTBOUND -->
                <add key="IB_OB_EnterpriseSkillGroup" value="EnterpriseSkillGroup"/>
                <add key="IB_OB_SkillGroupCreation" value="SkillGroupCreation"/>
                <add key="IB_OB_EnterpriseSkillGroupMap" value="EnterpriseSkillGroupMap"/>
                <add key="IB_OB_CallType" value="CallType"/>
                <add key="IB_OB_DialNumberMapping" value="DialNumberMapping"/>

                <!--NORAML OPERATIONS-->
                <add key="OPS_UserCreation" value="UserCreation"/>
                <add key="OPS_AgentSupervisor" value="AgentSupervisor"/>
                <add key="OPS_Rehire" value="Rehire"/>

                <add key="OPS_AgentTeamCreation" value="AgentTeamCreation"/>

                <add key="OPS_AgentSkillGroup" value="AgentSkillGroup"/>

                <add key="OPS_AgentTeam" value="AgentTeam"/>
                <add key="OPS_SupervisorTeam" value="SupervisorTeam"/>
                <add key="OPS_AgentTeamUpdate" value="AgentTeamUpdate"/>

                <!--Active Directory INFORMATION -->
                <add key="adURL" value="IQOR.QOR.COM"/>
                <add key="adUser" value="IQOR\ERP.IQ.QATCH"/>
                <add key="adPassword" value="+loS96bB8jNKv1JWXVLb0w=="/>

                <!--Others-->
                <add key="OTH_TeamUpdateEnable" value="true"/>
                <add key="OTH_ProgarmPoolIndEnable" value="false"/>

              </appSettings>

              <cafe.frameworks.foundationAbstraction>
                <authorization>
                  <adapters>
                    <add name="CafeProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE.AuthorizationAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" default="True"/>
                    <add name="EnterpriseLibraryProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary.AuthorizationAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                  </adapters>
                </authorization>
                <caching>
                  <adapters>
                    <add name="EnterpriseLibraryProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary.CacheAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" default="True"/>
                  </adapters>
                </caching>
                <dataAccess>
                  <adapters>
                    <add name="CafeProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE.DataAccessAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" default="True"/>
                  </adapters>
                </dataAccess>
                <exceptionManagement>
                  <adapters>
                    <add name="CafeProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE.ExceptionManagerAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" default="True"/>
                    <add name="EnterpriseLibraryProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionManagerAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                  </adapters>
                </exceptionManagement>
                <logging>
                  <adapters>
                    <add name="CafeProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE.LoggingAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" default="True"/>
                    <add name="EnterpriseLibraryProvider" type="Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary.LoggingAdapter, Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.EnterpriseLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                  </adapters>
                </logging>
              </cafe.frameworks.foundationAbstraction>


              <loggingConfiguration>
                <commonSettings loggingEnabled="true" logToTrace="true" useAdditionalParameters="true">
                  <loggingMode asynchronous="False"/>
                  <filters>
                    <allowedLogLevels>
                      <add name="Error"/>
                      <add name="Fatal"/>
                      <add name="Information"/>
                      <add name="Trace"/>
                      <add name="Warning"/>
                    </allowedLogLevels>
                    <allowedLogCategories>
                      <add name="Category"/>
                    </allowedLogCategories>
                  </filters>
                  <publishers>
                    <add name="DBLog" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.DBPublisher, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <add name="EventLog" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.EventLogPublisher, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <add name="MSMQLog" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.MSMQPublisher, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <add name="TextLog" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.TextFilePublisher, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <add name="XMLLog" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.XMLFilePublisher, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                  </publishers>
                  <formatters defaultFormatter="Text">
                    <add name="Text" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.TextFormatter, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                    <add name="Xml" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging.XMLFormatter, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                  </formatters>
                </commonSettings>
                <logSettings defaultCategory="Category">
                  <categories>
                    <add categoryName="Category">
                      <categorySettings>
                        <add levelName="Error">
                          <sinks>
                            <add publisherName="TextLog" formatterName="Text" fileName="AABLog.txt" maxFileSize="1MB"/>
                          </sinks>
                        </add>
                      </categorySettings>
                    </add>
                  </categories>
                </logSettings>
              </loggingConfiguration>


              <exceptionManagement>
                <policies defaultPolicy="UI Policy">
                  <add name="UI Policy" type="">
                    <exceptions>
                      <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
                        <handlers>
                          <add name="Log Handler" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement.LogHandler, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                        </handlers>
                      </add>
                    </exceptions>
                  </add>
                </policies>
                <messageSources defaultSource="Xml">
                  <add name="Xml" type="Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement.XmlMessageSource, Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.ExceptionManagement, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" source="D:\Cognizant\CAFE.NET 2.0\Foundation Services\QuickStart\Web\ExceptionMessages.xml"/>
                </messageSources>
              </exceptionManagement>


              <system.web>
                <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
                  <providers>
                    <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
                  </providers>
                </membership>
                <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
                  <providers>
                    <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
                  </providers>
                </roleManager>
              </system.web>
            <startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

The code where my application is crashing or giving exception is below:

```
public DataSet GetData(string statementId, string parameter)
    {
        object[] param = null;
        DataSet ds = null;
        try
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                param = new object[1];
                param[0] = parameter;
                ds = DataAccessFaçadeAdapter.ExecuteStatementForDataSet(statementId, param);
            }
            else
            {
                ds = ExecuteStoredProcedure(statementId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracer.Trace(TraceLevel.Error, "GetData() Exception is" + ex.Message);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

here the following line is where I get exception as this method is written in 3rd party dll for which I do not have any code

```
ds = DataAccessFaçadeAdapter.ExecuteStatementForDataSet(statementId, param);
```

And the Exceptions details are as below:

```
-       InnerException  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

        Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." string
```

Stack Trace as below:

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.AdapterFactory.GetAdapter[T]()
at IQOR.QATCH.IntegrationServices.DataAccessFaçadeAdapter.ExecuteStatementForDataSet(String StatementID, Object[] parameters)
at IQOR.AA.BackgroundTask.Exporter.GetData(String statementId, String parameter) in C:\\AutomationAnywhere_OLD_CODE\\AutomationAnywhere_OLD\\IQOR.AA.BackgroundTask - Copy\\IQOR.AA.BackgroundTask\\Exporter.cs:line 433
```

Stack Trace of 3rd Party dll is as below:

```
at Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data.AdoHelperFactory.GetConnectionString(String providerName)
at Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data.AdoHelperFactory.CreateHelper(String providerName)
at Cognizant.CAFE.FoundationServices.Data.AdoHelperFactory.CreateHelper()
at Cognizant.CAFE.Frameworks.FoundationAbstraction.Adapters.CAFE.DataAccessAdapter..ctor()
```

Please advise on how to resolve.

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting .Net Version 3.5

Comment: I have also added an image which shows exception details. May be it could be of some use to understand the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Determine if the third party DLL has an update. Usually system updates target discovered security holes and this targeted dll *may have some issue* related.

Otherwise you may want to implement a different method of data access or even move the application to .Net 4 which may have the latest methodology.

Comment: Hi Dear, I guess you are right that this may be because of some security hole and during windows update lot of security patches are installed. But we can not have an updated version of this 3rd party dll. I have changed the target framework to .NET 4, 4.5 and 4.6 but the issue remains the same.

Comment: I also can not change the data access code as  there are multiple 3rd party dlls in this project. I created a simple application and access the data from the same database in using simple ADO.NET in datasets and datareader, and everthing is working fine. Can you please help me here more on this...

Comment: @ParasChaudhary if the third party dll cannot be updated; your only course of action is to replace the code which uses it and build a new application without it.